# C# AVL tree find and insert

Tags: c#, performance, avl-tree

I have created an AVL tree implementation (Thanks to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/), and modified it a bit to fit my needs. Basically I want to be able to find a Node by a key (Like in a dictionary where I have Key-Value pairs).

I have tried to optimize the following code, that searches a word in the tree and if it doesn't exists it adds it:

```
// If the word doesn't exist, we do 2 searches and therefore we get O(2*lg(n)) = O(lg(n^2))
private void AddWordAppearance(string word)
{
    Word wordObject = wordsDictionary[word]; // Search the word in the tree - O(lg(n))
    // If the word doesn't exist, create the Word instance and add it to the dictionary.
    if (wordObject == null)
    {
        wordObject = new Word(word); // O(1)
        wordsDictionary.Add(word, wordObject); // O(lg(n))
    }

    // Some code that sets things in the wordObject.
}
```

I get the words from a text file, which is ~100MB, and my algorithm builds the tree in ~50 seconds.

What I tried to do is to create a new method in the AVL tree, like so:

```
// The key and Value are the generic type parameters of the AVL tree.
public Value FindOrAdd(Key key, Value toAdd)
{
    if (Root == null)
    {
        Add(key, toAdd);
        return toAdd;
    }
    
    DictionaryEntryNode<Key, Value> entry = Root, previous = null;
    
    while(entry != null)
    {
        previous = entry;
        if (entry < key)
        {
            entry = entry.right;
        }
        else if (entry > key)
        {
            entry = entry.left;
        }
        else
        {
            return entry.value;
        }
    }
    
    Insert(previous, key, toAdd);
    return toAdd;
}
```

Which searches for the key, and if it doesn't exists it would add the new value in the node.

I assumed it would work faster, because now my algorithm would need to do one search instead of two (search & insert).

But I get pretty much the same result.

Is there something I am missing?

- I calculate the time to build the tree using the Stopwatch class.

**=== EDIT ===**

Adding the add and insert methods

```
public void Add(Key key, Value value) => this.Root = Insert(Root, key, value);
private static DictionaryEntryNode<Key, Value> Insert(DictionaryEntryNode<Key, Value> node, Key key, Value value)
{
    if (node == null)
        return new DictionaryEntryNode<Key, Value>(key, value);
    // If the given key is smaller than the node's key, we try to insert in the left sub-tree.
    if (node > key)
        node.left = Insert(node.left, key, value);
    // If the given key is greater than the node's key, we try to insert in the right sub-tree.
    else if (node < key)
        node.right = Insert(node.right, key, value);
    // If the key already exists, we simply return the node (duplicates aren't allowed).
    else
       return node;

    // And Eventually re-balance the node.
    return Rebalance(node, key);
    }
```

Comment: You are missing a packing method.  Adding to a binary tree your tree may not be even (same depth from root to leaves).  So you results are not lg(n).  So a binary tree you need to pack every once in a while so your search is lg(n) where n is the max depth from root to leaves.

Comment: @jdweng What do you mean by "packing"¿
if balancing, then the tree is  balanced in the Insert method.

Comment: See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree.  Balancing take more time than a normal insertion.  So depending on the amount of time that is available you can either balance on the insertion or balance when time is available.

Comment: You insertion time is logN according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree.  the dictionary is probably using the same AVL method so you will not gain any time by writing the algorithm your self.  You don't normally include the insert time with the lookup time since you build the tree once, but do lookup lots of times.  It only pays to build a hash when you are going to save time.  Which means the time save for lookups is greater than the time to build hash.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, it helped me understand. I did it very late at night so I was pretty tired. I forgot that the balancing needs to happen on all nodes and not only the leaf. That is why I can't create a function that searches and inserts.

Thanks again